# Ist „ob ... oder nicht“ eine Wiederholung?

Tags: redundancy

Als nicht-Muttersprachler ist es kaum möglich zu merken, wann man in eine Redundanz gerät. Diese Frage geht um den richtigen Gebrauch der Subjunktion *ob*.

Wenn man mehr als zwei Möglichkeiten hat, braucht *ob* ein *oder*.

> Ich weiß ja gar nicht, **ob** ihr Kleid rosa, grün **oder** weiß war! Ich bin doch farbenblind.

Braucht man eigentlich das **oder**, wenn man nur zwei Möglichkeiten –etwa ja oder nein– hat? Intuitiv wäre die Antwort nein. Jedoch höre ich viel zu oft *ob … oder nicht*.

Sind z.B. die Wörter in Kursivschrift folgenden Satzes

> Ich weiß nicht, ob du kommst *oder nicht*.

entbehrlich bzw. überhaupt erlaubt?

Comment: Ich überlege noch, ob die Wahl der Farben gar richtig ist.

Comment: Korrektur: Es muss heißen »Ich bin doch *farbenblind*« (kein Substantiv, sondern ein Adjektiv). Auch möglich: »Ich bin doch *ein* Farbenblinder.« (mit Artikel)

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Danke sehr! :)

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: Es ist korrekt, aber würde man "ein Farbenblinder" wirklich benutzen? Zumindest im Deutschland-Deutsch klingt das sehr seltsam; definitiv das Adjektiv nutzen, also "farbenblind".

Comment: Kommt darauf an, falsch ist es definitiv nicht. _Das sieht doch ein Blinder_ zB ist absolut idiomatisch.

Comment: @Raphael: ich habe die Variante »ein Farbenblinder« als mögliche Zweitvariante genannt weil sie ja nicht falsch ist. Aber es ist eben die zweite Wahl.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Context is important, as always. Compare your sentence

> Ich weiß nicht, ob du [zu meiner Party] kommst oder nicht.

with

> Ich weiß nicht, ob du [gerade] kommst oder gehst.

which could be said when, say, meeting somebody in the hallway. (Note the comma -- there's always one before conjunction "ob"!) Hence, using the plain

> Ich weiß nicht, ob du kommst.

can be ambiguous in some situations.

So, in general you have to give the second alternative; if it's clear that the choice is binary or what the alternative is (from context), you can savely drop it.

**Rule of thumb:** If the English sentence would be "if A or B", use "ob A oder B."; if you'd say "whether A [or not]"¹, use "ob A."

*Nota bene:* "Isch weiß nisch, ob du kommst, oder?!" is definitely slang; "oder" is used as an exclamation resp. request for answer here. Also: "oder was?!"

---

1. As far as I know, using "or" with "whether" is wrong, but many people do it.

Comment: »there's always one before "ob"!« – Be careful with such absolutes as they have a tendency to turn out to be wrong: »Ich fragte ihn nach seinem Lieblingsgericht und ob er Hunger habe.«, »Dieser Satz ist ob seiner archaischen Grammatik vielleicht kein gutes Gegenbeispiel.«

Comment: A noteworthy variant to the case in which it is not clear what the second option is is a situation in which you have the option to decide for something but not chosing this option does not necessarily mean deciding against it. For example: »Heute fragt sie ihn, ob er sie heiraten möchte [oder nicht].« Without the *oder nicht,* he can decide to marry her today, but if he does not, this does not rule out marriage once and for all. With the *oder nicht,* she is asking him to agree now or never.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft: ad "ob" -- the second example is fair, but it's a different "ob"; I obviously meant the conjunction. I'm not so sure about the first example. "Ich fragte ihn, ob er Hunger habe." -- imho the comma has to be there. It's not clear to me why we can drop it in your longer version; should it not be "... und [danach], ob er..."?

Comment: @Wrzlprmft: ad marriage example: I understand what you are trying to do, but I don't follow the example. For me, both variants read binary, maybe because "fragen, ob heiraten" is such a strong thing, admitting essentially only two answers. If you want to allow for an answer "not now", you'd have to say "..., ob er sie jetzt heiraten möchte [oder nicht/später]". A better example is maybe something like this: "Ich frage ihn, ob der Kuchen möchte." Can he get ice cream instead, or is it cake or nothing?

Comment: 1) There is no comma according to § 74 E2 of the spelling rules. 2) Your cake example is not analogous to the marriage example. Analogous would be (in »Ich fragte ihn, ob er Kuchen möchte [oder nicht].«), if without *ohne nicht* he can still decide for cake later on, while with *ohne nicht,* the question would be his last chance to choose cake.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft 1) I see; dropping "danach" changes things. I learned something, thanks. 2) Sorry, I still don't see the time issue. Without further qualification, either sentence admits a later change of mind (to my ear, that is).

Answer (score 2):

> Braucht man eigentlich das oder, wenn man nur zwei Möglichkeiten –etwa ja oder nein– hat? Intuitiv wäre die Antwort nein. Jedoch höre ich viel zu oft ob … oder nicht.

Das **oder** brauch man schon.
Den Beistrich (das Komma) kann man dafür weglassen.

See:

> Ja oder Nein?

vs.:

> eins, zwei oder drei?

Comment: Welches Komma kann man weglassen, das vor "ob"? Ich glaube ja nicht, da wird eindeutig ein Nebensatz eingeleitet.

Answer (score 2):

> Ich weiß ja gar nicht, ob ihr Kleid rosa, grün oder weiß war!

Dieser Satz ist richtig. Man braucht "ob ... oder" in jedem Fall auch dann, wenn die beiden Möglichkeiten einander nicht ausschließen, sich die eine also nicht automatisch als das Gegenteil aus der anderen ergibt.

> Sie konnten sich nicht drauf einigen, ob sie weiße oder gelbe Blumen als Tischschmuck verwenden sollten.

Nur in Fällen, wo die Alternative zwingend ist kann man das ob weglassen:

> Ein Schachspieler fragte den anderen, ob er die weißen Steine wolle. (He offered the white pieces. As chess players know, White begins.)

Um Deine Ausgangsfrage zu beantworten:

> Kommst Du, oder nicht?

ist definitiv nicht falsch: *oder nicht* fungiert hier als Verstärkung, die man natürlich auch weglassen kann.